# R multiple fuzzy match agrep create variable

Tags: r, match, agrep

New to R. I would like to create a test by creating a variable (yes/no) that checks to see if first name OR last name fuzzy match to email address. If so, append a 'yes' variable to that row.

Data Example:

```
id firstname lastname email address match
1 patrick boyles patrickb@gmail.com yes
2 zeke cosmos zeke@gmail.com yes
3 foo foo abcd@gmail.com no
```

I understand that I need to use agrep. What confuses me is how to tell R to check 2 columns (first name and last name) and only check within that row.

Thanks
-The newbie

Comment: match to each other?  match to another dataset?  you are looking for `apply(dat, 1, function(x) { something with x[[2]] and x[[3]] } )`

Comment: completely fake email addresses and data here

Comment: first name OR last name fuzzy match to email address.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something to start with

```
library(stringdist) # install.packages("stringdist") b4, if you need to
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "id firstname lastname emailaddress match
1 patrick boyles patrickb@gmail.com yes
2 zeke cosmos zeke@gmail.com yes
3 foo foo abcd@gmail.com no")
df$match2 <- ifelse(with(df, stringdist(a = paste0(firstname, lastname), 
                                        b = sub("(.*)@.*", "\\1", emailaddress), 
                                        method = "lcs")) <= 7, 
                    "yes", "no")
df
#   id firstname lastname      email.address match match2
# 1  1   patrick   boyles patrickb@gmail.com   yes    yes
# 2  2      zeke   cosmos     zeke@gmail.com   yes    yes
# 3  3       foo      foo     abcd@gmail.com    no     no
```

Comment: might another approach be to split email address at the @ symbol and use an ngram (perhaps 3 to cover most situations) to match?  Longest common substrings (method = "lcs" doesn't deal with transpositions, as does method = "dl".  I just read Mark van der Loo's article so I am grateful to test out some ideas.

Comment: Yep, sounds like an interesting attempt for another answer to me. :)